# Display QuickLaunch on WebPartPage in sharepoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I'm trying to work out how to get sharepoint 2010 to display the quicklaunch on a web part page, the default.master trick I used in 2007 doesn't appear to work any more.

In my 2007 install, I simply edited the default.master and moved the quicklaunch code outside of the `PlaceHolderLeftNavBar` element but this doesn't have any effect in SP2010.

Thanks

Comment: Not really my field, but does anything of this help you out: http://www.endusersharepoint.com/EUSP2010/2010/06/04/navigating-sharepoint-2010-part-2-the-quick-launch/ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really want to place another copy of the quicklaunch on a web part here is the steps

1. Using Sharepoint Designer 2010 go to your site and navigate to Master Pages -> v4.master
2. Click edit file copy everything in the `<div class="ms-quickLaunch">` that should copy everything  you need for the quicklaunch to run.  For best result use the code view and hover over the quicklaunch and you should see the div, click on it and copy (Ctrl + C)
   [image]
3. Now you can paste that on another web part page and it should work, I tried it by creating a new test page and it worked

[image]

Comment: I cringe at the thought of how many architects are now trying to figure out how to deal with a 2-year-old SharePoint installation where some clueless dev changed OOTB master pages in SP Designer after finding this post.

Comment: @Rex M that wasn't the OP's suggestion, reread his post. And anyway, there is nothing wrong with modifying a master page in SPD. It only changes the master page for that site collection.

Answer (score 4):

A simple way to eneble Quick Launch Menu on WebPartPages is remove tags UIVersionedContentUIVersionedContent and PlaceHolderLeftNavBar using SharePoint Designer 2010.
See this article: http://denmartins.wordpress.com/2011/05/07/exibir-menu-quicklaunch-em-webpartpages/

Comment: this works because placeholders that are present on a custom page "replace" those in master page while rendering page. Removing the content placeholders in page causes left panel to be rendered normally in master page, as there's nothing to override them. See http://sdt.bz/content/article.aspx?ArticleID=33596&page=1 for example of this mechanism.

Comment: This is the best answer. I just solved a nagging issue where I created a custom page layout based on the WelcomeSplash.aspx OOB layout. I removed the line for the PlaceHolderLeftNavVar (UIVersionedContent was not in this one because it was for a different kind of page layout, I assume).

Answer (score 0):

You need to make changes in **v4.master** (in masterpage library), not in default.master.

For details on SharePoint 2010 master pages, please, follow this link:

http://sharepoint-sandbox.com/index.php?/Tips-and-Tricks/Customization/tip-80-sharepoint-2010-new-masterpages.html

Your masterpage trick on my SharePoint Foundation 2010 environment works fine.

**Anyway**, I don't think, that moving any standard code from placeholder is a good idea. If you want change position of quicklaunch menu, you should move the leftnavbar placeholder itself, including all the contents.

Placeholders are generally used to allow some pages, for example application pages, replace placeholder contents. So, if you hide the placeholder, and move it's contents out, these changes will be lost, and the standard menu will be shown. (and if you do not hide the placeholder, you can get two menus on one page :) )

Hope it helps!